# Unable to access ubuntu partition - GRUB issue

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I have huge problems in accessing Ubuntu. I have dual-boot and recently reinstalled windows. This caused a problem to grub boot-loader, in the sense that Ubuntu is completeley inaccessible. The first window at start says:

***Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB
lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible
device or file completions.***

Indeed if I type exit only windows will be initialized discharging the boot order. I tried many things but nothing seems to work. First I tried fixing using boot repair from live-USB but no recommended repair is shown. Moreover looking at advanced options (boot-repair) GRUB location & GRUB options are not available.
I then tried to reinstall GRUB with this classic procedure:
https://wiki.ubuntu-it.org/AmministrazioneSistema/Grub/Ripristino/Uefi
Unfortunately this command: mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi gives error since it looks like /boot/efi dir does not exist and no way can be created.

I specify that running lsblk gives me the following output:

nvme0n1             476.9G
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat      150M /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1      ESP

├─nvme0n1p2           2.9G

├─nvme0n1p3 vfat      1.4M /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3      EFISECTOR

├─nvme0n1p4 ext4    389.8M /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4

└─nvme0n1p5         179.7G

I think that my initial Ubuntu partition is ─nvme0n1p5. As you can see partition 3 looks a bit strange and no windows partition is shows. I think this is because previously I tried to analyze (from windows) the SSD with test disk and tried to recover the lost partition. I think I have somehow caused more issues since also my Windows now is corrupted and inaccessible. Maybe I lost it. FInally I use have UEFI interface. I specify that I do not care about any partition but Ubuntu, since it contains a lot of University coding projects. I am not very expert of this and I really need some help from someone who knows deeply this stuff.

Thank you all,

Dave

Comment: I think installing Windows after Ubuntu often causes problems as Windows doesn’t care about other operating systems and installs its boot loader over grub. I would probably reinstall Ubuntu and restore your data from backup. If you don’t have good backups (though of course you should), retrieve your data using a live usb session (copy to external media) then you can restore it to the new Ubuntu installation. I’m sure it’s possible to reinstall grub, but I think it’ll be tricky.

Comment: With an UEFI system, you must be careful to always boot in UEFI boot mode. How you boot install media for both Ubuntu & Windows UEFI or BIOS is then how it installs. Some tools to create installer may make it UEFI or BIOS only. And default setting of UEFI in UEFI settings is usually only for installed system. You still select the UEFI:xxxx to boot live installer in UEFI boot menu. If you have Boot-Repair link to Summary Report post that for better info.